# Make the cake php find query result to be changed array key with id value using Cake php itself

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How to make the cake php find query result array key to changed to id value using cake php?

```
$videos = $this->Video->find('all');

print_r($videos);
```

The array will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Video] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Video] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 8
                )

        )
)
```

How to change the array key with id value like below

```
Array
(
    [6] => Array
        (
            [Video] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [Video] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 8
                )

        )
)
```

Is it possible by cake php itself ?

Answer (score 8):

If you really need the data to be in this format, you can either use `afterFind` to set the IDs or you can use CakePHP's `Hash`/`Set` class.

Try this (since CakePHP 2.2)

```
$videos = $this->Video->find('all');
$videos = Hash::combine($videos, '{n}.Video.id', '{n}');
debug($videos);
```

Or this for CakePHP older than 2.2

```
$videos = $this->Video->find('all');
$videos = Set::combine($videos, '{n}.Video.id', '{n}');
debug($videos);
```

For more details see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html

If you might tell us why you need the data to be in this format, we can also suggest better ways for your doing since the data has not to be changed in this way.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. You can alter the result in afterFind(), look it up book.cakephp.org, but I would simply use the data as it is. I don't see any reason to add this additional overhead and complexity because the id is anyways available.

Answer (score 1):

In CakePHP 2.2 you could use

```
$videos = $this->Video->find('list');
pr($videos);
```

This would print every value with the id as key.

I don't know if you can use that in 1.3 but you can try...